# Xargs SED back into same file?

Tags: sed, xargs

Lets say I hit foo.html with `find`, i would like to pipe the contents back into foo.html

```
find . -iregex '.*\(html\|htm\)' -printf '%P\0' | \
xargs -0 sed -Ee "s:(http|https)\://(www.|)${domain}[?/]::g" \
> # to what? {\} ???
```

Right now it does not know what or where its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `-i` flag to `sed`, then it will modify the input file in place.

```
find . -iregex '.*html?' -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 sed -i -Ee "s:(http|https)\://(www.|)${domain}[?/]::g"
```

Comment: why `.*html?`, and btw, you're right I forgot in place, total brain fart ;) Plus one and waiting to accept.

Comment: Simplifying the regexp - it should match anything ending in `htm`, optionally followed by `l`.

Comment: `-i` requires an argument on BSD (i.e. OSX), you must pass `''` explicitly to not keep a backup.